# compare tables and fetch data in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, join

i have two table as following **1> users** **2>profile_action**

```
id  name                uid profile_id  action_type
1   aa                  1   2           bookmark
2   bb                  2   3           view
3   cc                  1   3           like
```

Now i want data based on following two condition

- where uid != m_session_id in profile_action table
- and remove users that i liked or bookmarked

so for that i have done following

```
$bscDta = $this->db->select('profile_id')
                            ->from('profile_action')
                            ->where(array('user_id'=>1,'action_type'=>'like'))
                            ->or_where('action_type','bookmark')
                            ->get();
$exceptionalId = $bscDta->result();
foreach ($exceptionalId as $exid) {
    $excptnlId .= $exid->profile_id.",";
}
$excptnlId = rtrim($excptnlId,",");
$quickSrch = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('users')
                    ->where(array('id!='=>1,'status'=>'Active'))
                    ->where_not_in('id', $excptnlId)
                    ->get();
$quickSrchData = $quickSrch->result();
```

But it will return following query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` != 1 AND `status` = 'Active' AND `id` NOT IN('2,3')
```

and o/p me

```
[id] => 3 's data
```

where expected o/p is blank. so is there any other way to do both operation 
 in single operation.

Comment: In the provided table structure and data column name is `type` and in the query, you are using `action_type`.

Comment: The secong thing is `where_not_in()` require array. So, don't convert array into comma separated string.

Comment: i've converted because of it will `exceptionalId` returns me `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [profile_id] => 2 ...`

Comment: Then convert into simple array not string.

Comment: my question is about `so is there any other way to do both operation in single operation`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with **JOIN**

```
$this->db->select('users.*, profile_action.profile_id');
$this->db->from('users');
$this->db->join('profile_action', 'users.id = profile_action.uid');
$this->db->where("(profile_action.action_type = like OR profile_action.action_type = bookmark)");
$this->db->where('user.user_id !=', 1);
$this->db->where('user.status', 'Acitve');
return $this->db->get()->result();
```